# Javascript letter Interval functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript and just here asking for some guidance and best practice questions:

I want the letters of the alphabet to be in an interval upon the press of a button. I seem to have the entire alphabet aspect of this project answered. But I now want separate buttons to control specific sets of letters. I tried to use the same functions and code for the vowels and other sets of letter but they only go through an interval once and stop.

Here my javascript code:

```js
var allLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
var vowels = 'aeiouy'.split('');

// start button function
let start = 0;
startButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (y = 0; y < allLetters.length; y++) {
       setTimeout(() => getRandom(allLetters), y * 1000);
    }
});

function getRandom (letters) {
    var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * allLetters.length)];
    console.log('set random', randomSet)
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;
};

// function that assigns entire alphabet
 function setRandomLetter() {
    var letter = allLetters[Math.floor(Math.random() * allLetters.length)];
    console.log('setRandom ', letter)
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = letter; 
}
```

Comment: your question is incomplete, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and then correct your question with missing code

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you're asking, you want startButton to cycle through all of the letters in the "allLetters" variable, and then you want another button on the page to cycle through another set of letters, for instance the letters in the "vowels" variable. Is that it?

Assuming that's what your asking, I think the problem is in the first line of the getRandom() function. You're passing in letters as a parameter, but you're taking the length of allLetters. Change this...

```
var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * allLetters.length)];
```

...to this...

```
var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
```

...and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Also! One more question, once the for loop has gone through the letter set, it stops. How would I set the loop to keep continuously going through the string?